# How to Add URL Rewrite for a Product with system value?

Tags: magento-1.9, url-rewrite, catalog-url-rewrite

I want to Add URL Rewrite for a Product with system value but when creating new URL Rewrite the option Type has been disabled. Where I can set up or how to enable this option?

See my screen below :
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have any solutions for this question, you can try my solution by using firebug remove disabled attribute then select system option and save

Comment: Thanks, this solution works but not good, but for now this is best solution